# TypeError : Cannot convert undefined or null to object javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting one type error with my JSON,
I am constructing a tree based on json, My JSON structure in not static fields and key values are dynamic,

When I have JSON data -

```
const data = [
  
  {
    "class": "abc",
    magList: "",
    authKeyMgmtMode: {
      "class": "OctetString",
      octets: "00"
    },
    wsEnable: true,
    wlans: true,
    wsle: true,
    busey: "567ff7c5[180188_180188,temp-ssid_Global_NF_e06779e9]",
    sspe: 0
  }
];
```

It works fine below is sandbox -
Code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-blackwell-dw5yn?file=/index.js

When I add one more value as

```
Ipv6Name: null,
```

In json array it's giving me error,

Error -
**Cannot convert undefined or null to object**

```
Object.keys(object).map((key, reactKey) => {
```

I have checked the references for same error, but not able to proceed.
Please guide me.

***Edited -***

> I noticed I was sending null to Object.keys but I was doing check in
> isPrimative function I was using the check but there were typo and few
> logical mistake, I was checking typeof value === null ,  Thanks for
> pointing out...

Comment: You're sending `null` to `Object.keys`

Comment: Yes, observed that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code because type of `null` is `object`:

```
isPrimative = (value) => {
    return (
      typeof value === "string" ||
      typeof value === "" ||
      typeof value === "number" ||
      typeof value === "boolean" ||
      value === null
    );
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed I am sending null to Object.keys but down in isPrimative function I was using the check but there were typo and few logical mistake, I was checking typeof value === null , Thanks for pointing out...

Comment: its written "primitive"